# Is unsecure access to JVM unused object possible?

Tags: java, scala, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a question for the JVM internals experts over here.

In the Java Virtual Machine, objects contents are stored in heap memory until they are Garbage Collected. Usually, GC occurs when there is no more memory available, so if the JVM has a huge lot of available space there can be a long time before GC happens.

On a security point of view, can you imagine a way for someone to access the JVM memory and get a dump of the heap space where unused objects waiting for GC could be found ?

I mean: if my program handle sensitive data, and I code my app in a way that does not leave references to these sensitive objects after execution of the process involving them, can a malicious software or sysadmin get access to the heap space and analyze it to find these sensitive data ?

Does the use of Scala change anything in terms of memory management and Garbage Collection ?

Comment: Bonus points: Apply the same attack to code that releases the memory eagerly (e.g. C++). More bonus points: Apply the same attack after the process, or the whole computer, was shut down.

Comment: @delnan did you know that until some Linux kernel versions ago, `free`d memory pages would not be sanitized? By `malloc`ing a few times you had a chance to get a partial dump of sensitive data (such as Firefox keyring), if you were lucky enough to be assigned the "right" page. After the process termination, the memory is still there, ready to be dumped. It will persist for some minutes (depending on the external temperature) even after shutdown, not to mention memory areas swapped to disk.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo A+, that's exactly what I was getting at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The admin of a system can certainly get access to the JVM memory. As a last resource, he/she could dump the JVM process memory and inspect that. You have to trust the platform you will be executing on, indeed.

You can reduce the time window in which such sensible data will be available unencrypted in memory by using `char[]` over `String` (which is immutable) and overwriting them with zeroes before leaving the scope in which you defined them, but there will be a timespan in which such data is available in cleartext.

At a lower level, you could encrypt memory, which will still leave an unencrypted key somewhere. You could also prevent memory pages from being swapped, which will not prevent dump anyway and could be a bad performance hit, if your application uses a relevant portion of RAM and the system isn't entirely devoted to it. Anyway, these solutions will only protect data at rest and, to my best knowledge, there is no JVM implementing them.

Using Scala will not change much, as this is a JVM specific issue, not related to what source language is compiled to bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can do this. You can using `jmap` to dump the heap and see discarded objects in VisualVM. AFAIK Scala is the same as it uses the same JVM.

The usual solution to this problem is to overwrite the object before discarding it.  Either you make the object mutable e.g. using a char[] or StringBuilder, or you overwrite it using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

> On a security point of view, can you imagine a way for someone to access the JVM memory and get a dump of the heap space where unused objects waiting for GC could be found ?

Yes.

There are various ways to do this, if the "bad guy" has privilege, or physical access to the machine.

> I mean: if my program handle sensitive data, and I code my app in a way that does not leave references to these sensitive objects after execution ...

Not exactly.  But if you are careful you can code your application to overwrite the sensitive data once it is no longer required.  However, this presupposes that you know and can control all of the objects that contain the sensitive data while in the JVM.

Even so, there are going to be time windows where someone could *grab* the data out of memory.  (Mind you, that is going to be true for *any* programming language!)

> Does the use of Scala change anything in terms of memory management and Garbage Collection ?

It makes no difference.